# Pandera/PySpark DataFrame error: TypeError: Unary ~ can not be applied to booleans

Tags: python, pyspark, pandera

I am trying to use pandera to validate a pyspark data frame's schema and coming across an unexpected error when validating constraints on a date column -- made all the more confusing by the fact that the error is not raised when applying the validation to an identical pandas data frame. As an example, I create pandas and pyspark data frames with the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"some_date": pd.to_datetime(["2022-10-16", "2022-10-17", "2022-10-18", "2022-10-19", "2022-10-20"])}
)
pyspark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
```

I then create the following schema for validation:

```py
from pandera.io import from_frictionless_schema

schema = from_frictionless_schema(
    {
        "description": "My Table",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "some_date",
                "title": "Some Date",
                "type": "date",
                "required": True,
                "constraints": {"maximum": "2022-10-18"}
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Upon running validation I get the following results:

```
>>> schema.validate(pandas_df)
...
<Check less_than_or_equal_to: less_than_or_equal_to(2022-10-18)>
failure cases:
   index failure_case
0      3   2022-10-19
1      4   2022-10-20

>>> schema.validate(pyspark_df.pandas_api())
...
TypeError: Unary ~ can not be applied to booleans.
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I am new to pandera but have tried searching the docs and stack overflow and have been unable to find any similar examples.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure exactly *why* this is happening, but I now know *what* is happening. I removed the max field constraint `"constraints": {"maximum": "2022-10-18"}` and instead replaced the functionality by adding the following (which should be logically identical) with a print function to debug:

```py
import pandera as pa

def foo(x):
    print(x <= "2022-10-18")
    return x <= "2022-10-18"

schema.columns["some_date"].checks.append(pa.Check(lambda x: foo(x)))
```

The output of the print function was

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: some_date, dtype: boolean
```

Along with the same error `TypeError: Unary ~ can not be applied to booleans.`. I tested a similar function on a numerical column and noticed that the printed Series dtype was `bool` rather than boolean (I still have no idea why). I decided to try modifying the function as follows:

```py
def foo(x):
    print(x <= "2022-10-18")
    return (x <= "2022-10-18").apply(bool)
```

This seemed to do the trick. For whatever reason, the check returned `boolean` for string/date fields and `bool` for numerical fields, casting all outputs to `bool` avoids the `TypeError` thrown by pandera..

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue while applying Pandera equality checks on PySpark dataframes. Interestingly, the exact same checks worked fine on regular Pandas dataframes with the same data; and other checks worked, too, it was just about `pa.Check.eq` ones.

Your solution helped me overcome this, but actually I found a more efficient way - instead of e.g. `pa.Check(lambda s: (s == VALUE).apply(bool))`, this was a bit quicker: `pa.Check(lambda x: x == VALUE, element_wise=True)`. One can read more about element-wise checks [here](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/checks.html#vectorized-vs-element-wise-checks).